# Create custom div element with special shape dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create some shapes like this :

[image]

These are 3 shapes.Then i want put some element on this shape.
I try to using border-radius property but it can't generate this shape.
Also i try to use `<img>` , `<map>` and `<area>` but i have problem with put elements on it.
What's your idea about it?

Comment: Use the `<canves>` tag, lets you paint inside a block element, i think its the easiest way to achieve what you desire.

Comment: @Imperative you mean using HTML5?could you make a sample?what about browser compatibility with this element?

Comment: have look at this page: lots of samples: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-tutorials-introduction/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just gotta be creative:

HTML:

```
<div id="circle">
    <div id="cover"></div>        
    <div id="innerCircle">     
        <div id="rect1"></div>
        <div id="rect2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   #circle { 
       width: 140px;
       height: 140px;
       background: red; 
       -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
       -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
       border-radius: 70px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: -50px;
    }

    #innerCircle { 
       width: 90px;
       height: 90px;
       background: white; 
       -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
       -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
       border-radius: 70px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        right: 25px;
    }

    #rect1 {
        width: 20px; 
       height: 90px; 
       background: white;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 5px;
    }

    #rect2 {
       width: 20px; 
       height: 90px; 
       background: white;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 5px;
    }

    #cover {
       width: 150px; 
       height: 80px; 
       background: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnSe7/

Or you can do something like this, curving the sides and using CSS3 rotate features to get the three shapes:

http://jsfiddle.net/RqWtC/1/

You will probably have to use HTML5 canvas to achieve the exact complex shapes you're requesting:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-custom-shapes/

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but i need 3 element.and i need generate this element dynamically. imagine save the coordinates in database and on page load, printing them on page.

Comment: well then your best bet is using an image. Why does it need to be code?

Comment: I want to put element on these elements,these elements are container elements, also i need bounds for my container elements. if i use DIV tag and set background-image for it , i haven't bound of my custom shape. now i don't know which element i should use.

Comment: Okay try the other JSFiddle I added

Comment: Thank you,and what about bounds?imagine if i write some text in div ,the text only must be in colored region.

Comment: Okay, see the updated fiddle. is that what you mean? very simple.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28187/discussion-between-tommy-coffee-and-saman-gholami)